# How to implement an async ignite cache store?

Tags: ignite

I am trying to implement 3rd Party Persistence using **Ignite.Net**.
I have implemented a CacheStore , wherein I am using Dapper as a 3rd Party ORM for database interaction in Load(),Write(),Delete() functions.

Can we make Load(),Write(),Delete() functions async ? Or do we have an async CacheStoreAdapter ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cache store in [write-behind mode](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/persistent-store#section-write-behind-caching). In this mode updates are collected and written to the underlying DB asynchronously with cache operations.

To enable it you should set [CacheConfiguration#writeBehindEnabled](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setWriteBehindEnabled-boolean-) configuration property to true.

Comment: Hi Denis, Thanks for your reply. But in my use case I am using async functions i.e PutIfAbsentAsync, ReplaceAsync and TryGetAsync functions of ICache<k,v> interface to put or get something from the cache. To enable 3rd party persistence I have implemented cache store using CacheStoreAdapter. So is there a async version of CacheStoreAdapter ?

Comment: Hi Mahesh, there's no special asycn cache store, you need to implement just regular CacheStoreAdapter, after this all async operations would be done in the special thread pool and won't block your code. So the same cache store would work fine with sync and async operations.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your reply. I am using TryGetAsync functions to get something from the cache. As the function name says  "TryGetAsync" it is an async operation.So accordingly I want my cache store implementation  to be asynchronous.For that I am using dapper ORM.Dapper ORM has async functions QueryAsync() and ExecuteAsync() to interact with the database which I intent to use.So is there a way I can achieve this ?

Comment: You don't have to use asynchronous ORM operations since your cache operations are asynchronous anyway. But if you really want to do this, you have to use async operations in your cache store implementation. But there is no simple way to know in read/write/delete operation is triggered by async cache operation or not.